# Perl: How to handle a stream of XML Objects without a root node

Tags: xml, perl, merge, stream

I need to parse a huge file with Perl. (so I'll be using a streaming parser ..)
The file contains multiple XML documents (Objects), but no root node. This causes the XML parser to abort after the first Object, as it should.
The answer is probably to pre/post fix a fake root node.

```
<FAKE_ROOT_TAG>Original Stream</FAKE_ROOT_TAG>
```

Since the file is huge (>1GByte) I don't want to copy/rewrite it, but would rather use a class/module that transparently (for the XML Parser) "merges" or "concatinates" multiple streams.

```
stream1 : <FAKE_ROOT_TAG>                 \
stream2 : Original Stream from file        >   merged stream
stream3 : </FAKE_ROOT_TAG>                /
```

Can you point me to such a module or sample code for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a trick pulled from [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=688120):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Parser;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc_file= shift @ARGV;

my $xml=qq{
     <!DOCTYPE doc 
           [<!ENTITY real_doc SYSTEM "$doc_file">]
     >
     <doc>
         &real_doc;
     </doc>
};

{ print "XML::Parser:\n";
  my $t= XML::Parser->new( Style => 'Stream')->parse( $xml);
}

{ print "XML::LibXML:\n";
  my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
  my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);
  print $doc->toString;
}
```

Comment: **this works, thank you** .. the only problem was, that the XML file has to be in the current working directory .. so I had to parse the file name to extract the path,   do a chdir(xml_path) before calling the xml parser and return to my calling dir after parsing.

Comment: @lexu - It should work even if files are not in the current directory. I'm testing on unix...maybe it doesn't like Windows paths? I don't know. If you're on Windows, maybe you have to change backslash to forward slash or double the backslashes?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example of how you might do it by passing a fake filehandle to your XML parser. This object overloads the `readline` operator (`<>`) to return your fake root tags with the lines from the file in between.

```
package FakeFile;

use strict;
use warnings;

use overload '<>' => \&my_readline;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $filename  = shift;

    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "open $filename: $!";

    return bless { fh => $fh }, $class;
}

sub my_readline {
    my $self = shift;
    return if $self->{done};

    if ( not $self->{started} ) {
        $self->{started} = 1;
        return '<fake_root_tag>';
    }

    if ( eof $self->{fh} ) {
        $self->{done} = 1;
        return '</fake_root_tag>';
    }

    return readline $self->{fh};
}


1;
```

This won't work if your parser expects a genuine filehandle (e.g. using something like `sysread`) but perhaps you'll find it inspirational.

Example usage:

```
echo "one
two
three" > myfile
perl -MFakeFile -E 'my $f = FakeFile->new( "myfile" ); print while <$f>'
```

Comment: This looks promising! I'll take a look tomorrow, at the office .. I've been 'playing' with tying file-handles .. but haven't gotten anyware yet. Thanks!

Comment: what perl version do I need for that use overload '<>' \&OverloadingSubroutine idiom? perldoc.perl.org/overload.html doesn't say .. or I didn't see.

Comment: @lexu, overload.pm has been in the core since pretty much forever.

Comment: thanks! I've since accepted runrig's answer and changed the title of the question. His approach solves the underlying problem with less overhead .. by simply avoiding it!